# JavaScript in Acrobat X: Printing Ranges of Pages

Tags: javascript, acrobat

In Adobe Acrobat (Version X), I want to send pages of a book in certain, unusual order to the printer. It turned out that this is more difficult than I thought. As Acrobat's print dialogue accepts manually typed in page ranges only with up to  100 characters, I need a better solution.

I hoped I could do this via Javascript.

For testing I used the following:

```js
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.printRange = [[2,5], [8,8], [10,10]];
this.print(pp);
```

Which is supposed to print pages 3-6, 9, 11

However, it does not do this. What I get printed is always the entire book (300 pages).

What is the issue here?

**Note: my real print job**

The page ranges used above are only for testing. What I eventually want is printing pages in specific order e.g.

`> 1, 151, 152, 2, 3, 153, 154, 4...` and so on

which obviously will have to be translated into the 0-based

`> [0,0],[150,150],[151,151],[1,1]...`

or at least, so I suppose.

An additional issue might occur with my array (of pages) being as long as 300 items (or more), and I have no idea whether the pp.printRange accepts that many...

**Another test**

I also tried

```
var pages = [[0,0],[150,150],[151,151],[1,1]]
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.printRange = pages;
this.print(pp);
```

Result: again, Acrobat ignores the array of page numbers and stubbornly prints the entire document.

**Printing is only one way...**

My task is to **re-order the  pages** of a book (following a certain algorithm). Printing them in certain, new order is just my lazy solution to re-ordering them. If the re-ordering could be done otherwise (e.g. extracting and then re-combining in the desired order), that would be a solution, too.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the example in the documentation, and added the "pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;" statement? With this, you would have feedback in the print dialog. Another thing to test would be if it works in Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: @MaxWyss Regarding Acrobat Reader DC: my current knowledge (or impression) is that Acrobat Reader DC does not support Javascript scripts to be executed via the Debugger dialogue (I get forwarded to Adobes website where they want to sell me an expensive monthly subscription for Acrobat Pro). In Acrobat DC Pro, I managed to get my script running, by the way. - As for the pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full: I will try this...

Comment: You got the correct lead by Sami Hult; I did check in the documentation, but overlooked the "available from Acrobat 11 on" mark. That said, there is no imminent need to use the interactionLevel parameter, unless for debugging purposes. It is correct that you can not execute JavaScripts from the Console in Reader, but you have an authoring tool, where you set up the scripts and run them in Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is that `printRange` parameter is first supported of Acrobat version 11 (XI). You can check these things out from the [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf).

I suggest that you, at any rate, check the version in your script, as suggested in the documentation:

```
if (typeof app.viewerVersion != "undefined" && app.viewerVersion >= 11.0)
{
    // Perform version specific operations.
}
```

Then, you can of course resort to other methods, if `printRange` is not supported. You could, e.g., remove the unwanted pages temporarily and then print the whole document - it's a bit hackish, but affects only versions below XI.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. - One thing perhaps to emphasize: my task is not simply to remove pages from a document, rather I have to  totally re-order the  pages (following a certain algorithm). Printing them in certain, new order is just my lazy solution to re-ordering them. If the re-ordering could be done otherwise (e.g. extracting and then re-combining in the desired order), that would be a solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually my solution to this problem was the following:

I purchased a tool (Javascript) made for such purposes by Gilad Denneboom (http://try67.blogspot.com/) who has also a lot of other tools for Acrobat, some of them for free, some for purchase (affordable).

The tool that solved my problem was his ***Extract Non-Sequential Pages*** script. There were some initial problems to get it fully running, but Gilad solved them instantly.

*Extract Non-Sequential Pages* does exactly what I sought (and what I first wanted to programme myself):

1) On starting it, it displays a dialogue asking for a sequence of pages numbers, e.g. 5,7,13,6,101,2,4,200-210 or whatever combination. This can be typed in, or copy-pasted in.

2) It then extracts pages in that order from the original document and collects them (in that order) in a new document. The new document is given some random name.

3) This new document can be stored, then printed, with pages in the new order.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pp = this.getPrintParams();

/*initial print range*/
pp.printRange=[[1,3]];
/*additional ranges are added to array through javascript push*/
pp.printRange.push([20,21]);}


pp.printerName="Adobe PDF";

this.print(pp);
```

Comment: Please add more of a description why this works for print ranges (not just that you can add lists to lists with push.)  Didn't Christian's original code correctly create a list of lists?